# I created a sphere on a chain link of meshes but it falls when in play mode

Tags: mesh

New to Blender. I'm trying to recreate a scene with a wrecking ball attached to a chain link. However after creating the sphere and placing it at the bottom of the chain link (other meshes) it just falls straight into the ground.

Also I was able to reorder the meshes in the collection but now I'm no longer able to.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Did you join the sphere to the bottom like so they are a single mesh?

Comment: Related : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/135915/29586

Comment: @RonJensen I don't know how to join it at the bottom. Let me try and find a tutorial for it.

Comment: @RichSedman let me check that link out and let you know. It looks very good.

Comment: Apologies for my noobness. This is my first attempt at any sort of computer animation.

Comment: In object mode, select the link, then shift select the ball. Press ctrl+j to join the two objects into 1

Answer (score 1):

The chain is just clipping through the sphere. You should make it in a way that is actually realistically possible so what you could do is put a whole through the sphere so that the chain can hang from there.

Comment: The UV Sphere then has to have spacing for chain links? I was following a YouTube tutorial but they simply just added the sphere within the link mesh.

Comment: then as other said he probably joined the sphere to the last mesh in the chain